# Magento 2: How Can I Add Field Notice To Checkout Fields?

Tags: checkout, uicomponent, field, magento-2.1.10

I'd like to add a comment to some checkout fields on `Magento 2.1.10` without using tooltips (that I need to remove). So I edited the `checkout_index_index.xml` and in shipping-address-fieldset section I've added the following:

```
    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string">My notice</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
```

Tooltip is hidden but no notice appears...

Any help would be very appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can add a custom template for a specific form field. This is perfectly explained in the Magento 2 devdocs. Take a look here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html

Answer (score 3):

1.Create a di.xml under 'etc' directory of your any custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="rewrite-checkout-fields" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2.Create a file called LayoutProcessorPlugin.php file under 'Namespace/Module/Model/Checkout'.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['notice'] = __('Please enter first name here'); 
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['notice'] = __('Please enter last name here'); 
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Note: here i add comment below first and last name you can do for others too.Please accept and vote if use full to you this will help others too.[image]